# Apache2 won't start in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, apache-httpd

I have seen many threads about this problem but the problem doesn't solved.

I'm trying to start `httpd.service` by this command :

```
$ sudo systemctl start httpd.service
```

Error :

```
Job for httpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status httpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

**P.S :**

```
$ journalctl -xn
```

The output of above command is :

```
-- Logs begin at Sat 2014-03-29 22:42:48 IRDT, end at Sat 2014-05-10 23:58:05 IRDT. --
May 10 23:55:51 localhost systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
May 10 23:55:51 localhost sudo[18583]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 10 23:58:05 localhost sudo[19575]: kamix : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/kamix ; USER=root ; COM
May 10 23:58:05 localhost sudo[19575]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root 
May 10 23:58:05 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Apache Web Server...
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
May 10 23:58:05 localhost apachectl[19578]: httpd: Syntax error on line 59 of /etc/httpd/con
May 10 23:58:05 localhost sudo[19575]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 10 23:58:05 localhost systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited sta
May 10 23:58:05 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache Web Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
```

Comment: `httpd: Syntax error on line 59 of /etc/httpd/con` Post your config.

Comment: Even if your system uses `systemd`, you can still do a `apachectl configtest` to debug configuration problems.

Comment: @mid_kid `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` content is here http://pastebin.com/1K5nn9iZ

Comment: @BruceEdiger Your cammand same error : `httpd: Syntax error on line 59 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_authn_default.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authn_default.so`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output of `apachectl configtest`, my Arch linux server's files, and a little googling, it appears that [there's an issue](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1392727) when you [upgrade Apache from 2.2 to 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html). I vaguely remember having this problem last year sometime. I'm going to advise saving `httpd.conf` somewhere, doing `pacman -R apache`, and then `pacman -S apache`. Use some difference tool to compare the Apache 2.4 `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` with the one you saved, and make any necessary changes to the new `httpd.conf`.  There will likely be only a few necessary changes. I personally got rid of some named virtual servers that I didn't need.